# IE Background issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Please check out the slideshow at the top of **[www.ysa.org/frontpage](http://www.ysa.org/frontpage)** on **IE** (preferably 8 or lower) and compare to **Chrome/Firefox**. In IE 8 (which is what I'm testing on), the background of the slideshow area is white while in Chrome/Firefox it is normal. How do I fix this?

Let me know if you don't see what I'm talking about and I'll just post a screenshot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `<div class="views_slideshow_singleframe_slide views_slideshow_slide views-row-2 views_slideshow_singleframe_hidden views-row-even" id="views_slideshow_singleframe_div_frontpage_slideshow-block_1_1" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; filter: alpha(opacity=0); BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; zoom: 1; display: none; top: 0px; left: 0px;" jQuery1282861198234="4" cycleH="330" cycleW="960">`

just delete the `filter: alpha(opacity=0); BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff;`

Comment: awesome! I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

After checking it on IE8 Web Developer tool, looks like  is getting an inline style (most likely from javascript) of filter: alpha(opacity:0); background color: #fff;